# Does vagor mean to bleat?

Tags: vocabulary

Normally I think of vagor as a deponent verb meaning to wander.

However, in the following online dictionary, they list **vagor** as meaning instead to bleat or wail or cry: https://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/latin-english-dictionary.php?parola=vagor

I cannot find this meaning in Lewis & Short. Is this just an error in the online dictionary or am I looking in the wrong place in Lewis & Short?

Answer (score 5):

No, it doesn't mean "to bleat," because it's not a verb.  According to your dictionary, it is a third-declension masculine noun, which Lewis & Short, sure enough, also know about, albeit with a [slightly different meaning](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dvagor2):

> a sounding, sound

The meanings given by your dictionary seem to be based on the idea that it is synonymous with *vagitus*. That noun, based on the verb *vagire*, in the strict sense refers to the noises made by infants.